# to find how many times a number occurs in two situations

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, range

Q) neighbours m and n order takeout on new year's. after this, they order at a fixed interval. write a python program to find out the number of days both will order on the same day in january.

for example: if m orders every 2 days after jan 1st and n orders every 3 days after jan 1st, the number of times they order on same day is 6 (include jan 1st)

I tried this.

c1 and c2 in the while loop will give the days on which they ordered takeout. I was planning to add all the values of c1 and c2 to two separate lists and compare them?? i'm not sure if that's possible, and if it is this is wrong code. I'm not sure how to do this. please someone help

```
m=int(input())
n=int(input())
c1=1
c2=1
count=0
while c1 in range(1,31):
    c1=c1+m
    l1=[1,c1]
while c2 in range(1,31):
    c2=c2+n
    l2=[1,c2]
for x in l1:
    for y in l2:
        if x==y:
            count=count+1
        print(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m=int(input())
n=int(input())
c1=1
c2=1
l1=[]
l2=[]
count=1
while c1< 32:
    
    c1=c1+m
    l1.append(c1)
    
while c2< 32:
    c2=c2+n
    if c2 in l1:
        l2.append(c2)
count+=len(l2)
print(count)
```

as 1 January is  common in all times so i started count from 1

Comment: This complexity of this solution is increasing quadratically, you shouldn't have to get all combinations of days.

Answer (score 1):

*NB. the solution below is **efficient**, you shouldn't need to have more than 31 iterations in your code (actually no more than 31//3). Testing all combinations of days is useless and will lead your code to be not scalable.*

This is easily solvable using comprehensions/generators.

The days where they order together are both multiples of the step (counting from 0).

You can get those days using:

```
[day+1 for day in range(31+1) if not (day%2 or day%6)]

# output: [1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31]
```

*NB. `day%x` returns `0` if `day` if a multiple of `x`, so `not (day%2 or day%6)` is True when `day` is simultaneously a multiple of `2` and `6`.*

However, you quickly realize that you do not need to test all days, only those of the largest multiplier:

```
[day+1 for day in range(0, 31+1, 6) if not (day%2 or day%6)]

# output: [1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31]
```

If you only want the count of days:

```
sum(1 for day in range(0, 31+1, 6) if not (day%2 or day%6))

# output: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to correct your code, you should know that `=` does not add items to a `list`. It just re-writes it. So, this is the correct way of your code:

```
m=int(input())
n=int(input())
c1=1
c2=1
count=0
l1 = []
l2 = []
while c1 in range(1,32):
    c1=c1+m
    l1.append(c1)
while c2 in range(1,32):
    c2=c2+n
    l2.append(c2)
for x in l1:
    if x in l2:
        count=count+1
print(count)
```

**BUT** I think there is a better way to solve this question. as you see, the days that they both order is the `LCM` of the `m` and `n` and its `multiples` lesser than `31`. So the code would be something like this:

```
import math
count = 0
i = 2
lcm = math.lcm(m, n)
while lcm <= 31:
    counter = counter + 1
    lcm = lcm * i
    i = i + 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: This complexity of this solution is increasing quadratically, you shouldn't have to get all combinations of days.

Comment: @mozway are talking about my solution or the questioner's solution?  anyhow, the maximum is 31. so is it really an issue?

Comment: i think in the top code, count should be set to 1 instead of 0

Comment: @students no `count = 0` is right. the problem is in the `range()`. when you call `range(1,31)` it actually counts from `1` to `30` and ignores the `31`. I edit my code.

Comment: @Shireen ohh okay got it thank you

Comment: @Shireen, both. You read the list twice to get the steps and then test each step against the others. Of course here the timing won't be noticed in the toy example, but I doubt the purpose of the code is to really get this info. If the purpose is to learn, then yes it matters a lot to do the right thing. Check my answer for example ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create two sets. One has the start day and additional values incrementing by 2 up to and including the last day of the month. The second is like the first but increments by 3. You can then perform a bitwise *and* on the two sets and count the length of the resulting set. Although rather obtuse, you could do it in one line of code thus:

```
print(len({i for i in range(0, 31, 3)} & {i for i in range(0, 31, 2)}))
```